# Can a video clip be stored in a databin and then accessed for processing?

Tags: wolfram-cloud, video, databin

I want to upload a video clip to the Wolfram cloud and then access it from the cloud for video processing in the cloud.

I saved a video clip to a databin as follows first I create a FormObject

```
CloudDeploy[
 FormPage[
  {"video" -> 
    QuickTime | 
     MP4}, 
  DatabinAdd[myDB, #video] &],
 Permissions -> "Public"
 ]
```

Then I access the URL returned by the CloudDeploy
I get a form to upload a video, which I do.

What I see in the databin is

```
Video["/tmp/UserTemporaryFiles/public/13673/4d1/4d1c2014-ae34-4e3b-\
80ba-8d2da7d6aa43/upload-directory-0/trim.5D7FEF2A-41DA-430C-B5BF-\
7C37C80997D9.MOV", Appearance -> Automatic, 
 AudioOutputDevice -> Automatic, SoundVolume -> Automatic]
```

I do the following in the cloud in a cloud notebook, attempting to create a Video object from the tmp file

```
vid = Video["/tmp/UserTemporaryFiles/public/13673/4d1/4d1c2014-ae34-4e3b-80ba-\
8d2da7d6aa43/upload-directory-0/trim.5D7FEF2A-41DA-430C-B5BF-\
7C37C80997D9.MOV"]
```

And I get the dreaded File not found error.

My question is - Is it possible to save a video clip as a binary object to a databin and retrieve it for video processing?  It seems like the uploaded file is saved to a tmp file and then deleted before it can be accessed. So how do I achieve what I am trying to do as stated in the first sentence? Thanks much.